# Async Function Promise (axios)

Tags: javascript, api, asynchronous, global-variables

I am trying to fetch the gas prices from ethgasstaion and work with this value in the global scope. Is there a way that I can include a global variable in my .then() part and assign the value of my async function to that variable?

I get the right value but can't assign it to the global variable.

```
   // Eth Gas Station
let fast_value = 0;
async function  getCurrentGasPrices() {
  let response = await axios.get(process.env.ETH_GAS_Station_API)
  let price = {
      fast: response.data.fast
  }
  return price
}
getCurrentGasPrices().then(value => {
  fast_value += value.fast;
    })

console.log(fast_value)
```

Appreciate the help!

Comment: What error do you have?

Comment: I get an undefined statement if I try to console.log(fast_value)

Comment: What if you console.log it inside then clause?

Comment: I just wanted to check whether the value is now defined in the global scope. So that I can use it for further calculations.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap everything into an immediately invoked async function, so we can use await inside:

```js
(async () => {
    let fast_value = 0;
    async function getCurrentGasPrices() {
        let response = await   axios.get(process.env.ETH_GAS_Station_API);
        let price = {
            fast: response.data,
        };
        return price;
    }

    let response = await getCurrentGasPrices();
    fast_value = response.fast;
    console.log(fast_value);
})();
```